# Difference between Manjaro editions

Tags: manjaro

I want to install Manjaro. At the [website download link](https://manjaro.org/download/), there are multiple options as shown here:
[image: Manjaro editions]

What is the difference between these editions?

Comment: ARM is for ARM Processors, 32-bit is for 32-bit Processors, Previews are non stable versions like Beta, the rest, I don't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not the editions but the **tags** for the editions that pop up when you click on the tags.

The real editions below are mainly about which Desktop Environment to chose (XFCE, KDE, Gnome, Cinnamon, etc.) and the Archtitecture (32-bit, ARM, ...).

So if you want a "Begginer-friendly" "Flagship edition", click both and see the editions that match both tags.

[image: begginner-friendly flagship editions]